# is there private MAC address space?

Tags: macos

For IP addresses there are 10.x.x.x , 192.168.x.x IP address that can
be used for private networks. Is there something similar for MAC
address of network cards that can be safely used without applying for the permission from IEEE？

Comment: interesting question, but fits better on serverfault IMHO

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use a "Locally Administered Address"
https://web.archive.org/web/20100706092655/http://standards.ieee.org/regauth/groupmac/tutorial.html or https://standards.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/import/documents/tutorials/macgrp.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Are you saying that the following(48bit) is legal?

(MSB)                                                  (LSB)
xx10 xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx

x may be 0 or 1

Comment: The local/universal bit is the second least significant bit of the most significant byte of the address. Try the Wikipedia link, maybe it's clearer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address

Comment: If it was just for temporary use, could one also use an unassigned address: http://www.iana.org/assignments/ethernet-numbers/ethernet-numbers.xhtml#ethernet-numbers-2 ?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what @Tergiver correctly said, you need to be careful about the ordering in which the bits are sent (it may not be obvious). If my calculations are correct, this means that the MAC address (as normally written) must start with x2, x6, xA or xE (where x is in [0-F]).

(The ones I've been given my network administrator start with 0E:)